# update array index value as object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router

I want to update the value of a key in an array with the immutability-helper addon.

my code looks like this:

```
class StorageForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        volumes: [{local: 'test', remote: 'test2'}],
    };
  };

  _handleLocalPathData(event, index) {
    const path = event.target.value;
    const data = this.state.volumes[index];
    data.local = path;

    const tmpData = update(this.state.volumes[index], {$set: [data]});

    this.setState({
        volumes: tmpData
    });
 };
}
```

but volumes aren't the updated one. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set `local` property of object in array at `index` position:

```
const newVolumes = update(this.state.volumes, {
  [index]: { local: { $set: path },
};
this.setState({ volumes: newVolumes });
```

Comment: well, I tried this already but for [index] I used this.state.volumes[index]. I'll try it later.

Answer (score 0):

make the _handleLocalPathData return the tmpData and inside the class call the function and use this.setState({volumes: tmpData}).
why because of the context of **this** is not refering to the StorageForm  class